# Free description of the Kameda-Weiner algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, automata, finite-automata

I found the paper "On the State Minimization of Nondeterministic Finite Automata" which, I assume, contains the Kameda-Weiner algorithm that I've been searching for. It's behind a paywall though. I'm just a hobbyist. Can someone explain it, or point me to another source?

Comment: should be noted this was cross-posted to Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039896/free-description-of-the-kameda-weiner-algorithm-x-post-from-cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented it here: https://github.com/coder0xff/parlex_legacy/blob/132e4a23a599140d22b18ead832626f0c607340f/Automata/NFA.cs#L641

I've never gotten around to describing it, but to be brief, it's very involved. The only way to gain a useful understanding of the algorithm is to read the paper start to finish.

Comment: Apologies. It's in C#.

Comment: what/where is Nfa.Minimize? is there any descr anywhere?

Comment: The name is Minimized. It's in the linked file near the bottom. As for a description, a paper is required to explain it. It has no documentation as it is a component of a larger project, but in short, create an NFA and add states. Also add some of the state's to the StartState and AcceptState members. Add entries to the transitionfunction member and you have an nfa. Call Minimized on it and it'll return a new NFA.

Comment: It's a bit slow for anything more than a few states, since it is np-hard after all, but I plan on adding some optimizations in the near future. Note that currently this is state minimization, and the number of transitions may not be minimal, but it's fairly easy and I'll be extended it to do so as well.

Answer (score 2):

Brzozowski's paper on arXiv might have a full account of the algorithm. He's one of the pioneers in what I've termed the "algebraic approach" for formal language and automata theory - best known for invoking the "Brzozowski derivative" (aka left-quotient) to describe the state transition of a regular language in algebraic terms. It's the same operation that we used in producing a dramatically simpler proof of Parikh's theorem in 1999. For commutative Kleene algebras, the operator actually *is* a derivative operator complete with its own version of Taylor's Theorem.

In the paper, https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.5585, Brzozowski brings the derivative/quotient infrastructure to bear; but from a casual reading of the paper, I can't tell if he's described the Kameda-Weiner method in full generality or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a succinct but somewhat abstract description of the technique based on [1]. Also reading [2] to understand the universal automaton before approaching this description is recommended.

I am also assuming that you are familiar with quotients and some basic properties of them (e.g, Myhill-Nerode Theorem). These topics can be found in an (slightly less) introductory book on automata theory.

Alternately, you can look at [link](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2016/6251/) for paper [3] (accessible for free)

---

Let $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$. If $L$ is regular, one can find finitely many words $U = \{ u_1, u_2, \cdots u_n \}$ such that (1) each quotient $u_i^{-1}L$ is distinct from $u_j^{-1}L$ and (2) for all $w \in \Sigma^*$, there exists some $i$ such that $w^{-1}L =  u_i^{-1}L$.

Similarly, there are words $V = \{v_1, v_2, \cdots v_m\}$ such that similar conditions are true for the right quotients $Lv_i^{-1}$.

A factorization of $L$ is a pair $(X, Y)$ (where $X$ is the left factor and $Y$ is the right factor) such that $XY \subseteq L$ which is maximal, i.e, there does not exist $(X', Y')$ satisfying the same property such that $X \subset X'$, $Y \subset Y'$ (with strict containments).

Observe that the left factor of a factorization determines the right factor uniquely and vice-versa. Furthermore, note that any interesection of left quotients is a right factor and any intersection of right quotients is a left factor. This is, in fact, a characterization of left (resp, right) factors, in the sense that any left (resp, right) factor is an intersection of right (resp., left) quotients.

It follows that there are finitely many factorizations of a regular language $L$. Further, any right (resp., left) factor can be described using a subset of $U$ (resp., $V$).

Factorizations can be used to define an automaton that recognize $L$. The states of this automaton are factorizations. Suppose $(X, Y)$ and $(X', Y')$ are factorizations and $a \in \Sigma$.  The transition $(X, Y) \rightarrow^a (X', Y')$ exists iff $XaY' \subseteq L$. The initial states of this automaton consist of all those $(X, Y)$ such that $\varepsilon \in X$ and the final states contain all those $(X, Y)$ such that $\varepsilon \in Y$.

A grid is a pair $(U', V')$  with $U' \subseteq U$ and $V' \subseteq V$ such that for any $u \in U'$ and $v \in V'$, $uv \in L$. Corresponding to a grid, we have factorizations $(X_{V'}, Y_{U'})$ which consist of intersections of the corresponding quotients.

A grid cover is a collection of grids $\{ (U_\alpha, V_\alpha)\}_{\alpha \in I}$ with the following property: If
$u \in U  \setminus (\cup_\alpha U_\alpha)$ and  $v \in V  \setminus (\cup_\alpha V_\alpha)$, then $u v \not \in L$. Again, if the language $L$ is finite, a finite grid cover always exists.

Corresponding to a finite grid cover, a set of factorizations are associated. Consider the subautomaton induced in the Universal Automaton by this exact set of factorizations. This is the Kameda-Weiner Automaton.

You can find a small KW automaton by choosing your grids appropriately.

---

[1] Minimalizations of NFA Using the Universal Automaton, by L. Polak (2005) [IJFCS]

[2] The Universal Automaton, by S. Lombardy & J. Sakarovitch (2008) [Logic and Automata]

[3] New Interpretation and Generalization of the Kameda-Weiner Method, by H. Tamm (2016) [ICALP]